# Expected Number of elements in a QUEUE

Tags: probability

Suppose i have a queue and each access is read with probability p and write with probability 1-p then 
a)How many elements are there after i operations.
2)Expected Number of steps needed to search an element.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: It wont be binomial distribution as there can be empty reads also

Comment: Having $i$ failures after $i$ tries is not a part of the events of a binomial distribution?